# .NET get process ID of my application in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way in .NET to get the process ID (or just the `Process`) of the program making the call?

`Process.GetCurrentProcess()` gets the `Process` that's currently active, i.e., the one the user is using right then.  I need the `Process` of my own app which is likely not active at the time I'm calling it.

I could call `GetCurrentProcess()` on `Window.Activated` and store it in a private field, but there's no absolute guaranty (I believe) that that event will ever fire if the app is opened in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken.. [GetCurrentProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx) returns:

> A new Process component associated with the process resource that is running the calling application.

It does not (necessarily) return the process associated with the currently active window.

When the docs refer to the "active" process, that means the currently executing process, i.e. the calling process. The active window may or may not belong to the active process, since of course a process can execute without owning the foreground window, or any window at all.

Comment: Is this the same call that the .NET Process object uses?  That is, is .NET's `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` just a wrapper of this COM one?  I had been using Process.GetCurrentProcess() to allow me to activate my app and then immediately reactivate the one that had been active.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link - fixed. I'm quoting MSDN on Process.GetCurrentProcess.

Comment: But yes, the native call does the same thing.

Comment: That's weird, because I see both your quote and "Gets a new Process component and associates it with the *currently active* process."

Comment: The currently active process is the caller. Look at the "return value" section of my link.

Comment: Just to add, if you are using .NET 5 or later you can (and probably should) use `Environment.ProcessId` instead - if all you need is the ProcessId: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1837)