# Keep track of the process Ids of the processes spawned from my program

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I need to keep track of the Ids of the processes spawned from my program, including the id of my C# application's root process i.e. the process the user started by double-clinking its icon.

Has anyone else needed to do this?

What's a good reliable way of doing this?

I'm imagining a List(), but a DataTable might be even better depending on available data.

Comment: What is it you call the "root process"? Does you app spawn additional processes?

Comment: @Thomas Levesque I didn't know how else to describe it. By root process I mean the first process created when users of my app double click the exe

Comment: Usually, an app will only be a single process. Are you perhaps mixing terminology up here?

Comment: @BugFinder I tried Process.GetProcessId(), but I read that it does not guarantee the process id of the process calling it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354906/net-get-process-id-of-my-application-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I possibly am. Are threads different to processes?

Comment: You surely mixed it up: If you read the answer to the SO question you just mentioned, you'll see that `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id` is the correct way to go.

Comment: @René Vogt I see, I was lumping threads and processes into the same pot. So, that solves part of my problem. All that's left is how to find the id if my application launches a process? Does that process record its parent's process id, or do I have to record them manually using something similar to zhaojingbo's method below?

Comment: Parent process IDs seem somewhat tricky on windows. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486717/finding-parent-process-id-on-windows and use the `ManagementObjectSearcher` as in zhaojingbo's answer.

Comment: I think I know how to solve this. I'll code it up and post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string process = "notepad.exe";
 string sql = string.Format("select * from win32_process where name='{0}'", process);
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sql);
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
 {
       string pid = mo.Properties["ProcessId"].Value.ToString();
       string cimtime = mo.Properties["CreationDate"].Value.ToString();

       cimtime = cimtime.Substring(0, cimtime.IndexOf('.'));
       string format = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
       DateTime startTime = DateTime.ParseExact(cimtime, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
       sb.AppendFormat("PID:{0}\t启动时间:{1}", pid, startTime);
       sb.AppendLine();
 }
 MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var id = currentProcess.Id;
```

You will need a refernce to

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```